# Mathematica DSolve does nothing

Tags: differential-equations

So I am trying to solve:

```
***DSolve[{Derivative[1][c1][
    t] == (0. - 
      9.48262*10^33 I) ((-2.40987*10^-22 + 4.97993*10^-23 B^2 + 
         1.84752*10^-23 \[Xi]1 + 1.24163*10^-23 \[Xi]2) c1[
        t] + (-3.68681*10^-23 + 3.1645*10^-24 B^2 + 
         2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]1 + 2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]2) c2[t]), 
  Derivative[1][c2][
    t] == (0. - 
      9.48262*10^33 I) ((-3.68681*10^-23 + 3.1645*10^-24 B^2 + 
         2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]1 + 2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]2) c1[
        t] + (-2.40987*10^-22 + 4.97993*10^-23 B^2 + 
         1.24163*10^-23 \[Xi]1 + 1.84752*10^-23 \[Xi]2) c2[t]), 
  c1[0] == 0.948683, c2[0] == 0.316228}, {c1[t], c2[t]}, t]***
```

But mathematica does nothing; it just gives me back the expression.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the equations

```
eqns = {Derivative[1][c1][
      t] == (0. - 
        9.48262*10^33 I) ((-2.40987*10^-22 + 4.97993*10^-23 B^2 + 
           1.84752*10^-23 \[Xi]1 + 1.24163*10^-23 \[Xi]2) c1[
          t] + (-3.68681*10^-23 + 3.1645*10^-24 B^2 + 2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]1 + 
           2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]2) c2[t]), 
    Derivative[1][c2][
      t] == (0. - 
        9.48262*10^33 I) ((-3.68681*10^-23 + 3.1645*10^-24 B^2 + 
           2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]1 + 2.0369*10^-24 \[Xi]2) c1[
          t] + (-2.40987*10^-22 + 4.97993*10^-23 B^2 + 
           1.24163*10^-23 \[Xi]1 + 1.84752*10^-23 \[Xi]2) c2[t]), 
    c1[0] == 0.948683, c2[0] == 0.316228} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

sol = DSolve[eqns, {c1, c2}, t];
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {{True, True, True, True}} *)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! But could you explain why?

Comment: Exact solvers (e.g., `Solve`, `Reduce`, `DSolve`) can encounter difficulties in working with approximate real numbers. For example, you may encounter a warning message that `Solve` was unable to solve an equation with inexact coefficients, that it solved by rationalizing the coefficients, and then numericized the result. However, **Mma** does not appear to try this workaround with `DSolve`. Consequently, when `DSolve` returns unevaluated with approximate real numbers, it is worth trying to solve after converting all equations to exact forms. This won't help in all cases, but did in this case.